# ZXing 2.1: com.google.zxing.NotFoundException

Tags: java, exception, barcode, zxing

I am attempting to get a successful result with the [ZXing](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/) 2.1 library.  I am using Java 1.6 on Mac OS X 10.7.5.  I am able to encode text but not decode any images.  Rather, all I get are one-line stack traces of `com.google.zxing.NotFoundException`.

This seems straightforward but I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.  Here is a simple test to reproduce.  It encodes a couple barcodes to images and then decodes the images from memory:

```
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Try UPC-A.
        try {
            testEncodeDecode(BarcodeFormat.UPC_A, "012345678905");  // Valid UPC-A.
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Try EAN-13.
        try {
            testEncodeDecode(BarcodeFormat.EAN_13, "9310779300005");  // Valid EAN-13.
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void testEncodeDecode(BarcodeFormat barcodeFormat, String text)
        throws WriterException, NotFoundException, ChecksumException, FormatException, IOException {

        // Size of buffered image.
        int width = 200;
        int height = 100;

        // Encode to buffered image.
        Writer writer = new MultiFormatWriter();
        BitMatrix bitMatrix = writer.encode(text, barcodeFormat, width, height);
        BufferedImage bufferedImage = MatrixToImageWriter.toBufferedImage(bitMatrix);

        // Write to disk for debugging.
        String formatName = "png";
        File outputFile = new File(text + "." + formatName);    
        ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, formatName, outputFile);

        // Decode from buffered image.
        LuminanceSource source = new BufferedImageLuminanceSource(bufferedImage);
        BinaryBitmap bitmap = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(source));
        Reader reader = new MultiFormatReader();
        Result result = reader.decode(bitmap);

        // Never gets this far!
        System.out.println("result=" + result.getText());
    }
}
```

Output will simply be

```
com.google.zxing.NotFoundException
com.google.zxing.NotFoundException
```

I'm stumped!  Thanks for your help.  Output images are attached for your reference.

UPC-A [image: abc]
EAN-13 [image: def]

Comment: Save and share the images you are generating -- something may be going wrong there.

Comment: Sure thing.  Images are attached and code now reflects this step.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing a similar problem in the beginning but passing hints solved it for me.
You can try passing `TRY_HARDER` first. It should work. If it doesn't then try passing the `POSSIBLE_FORMATS` hint as you already know the formats. Check and see if both the hints work.

Answer (score 0):

From looking at this briefly, I think the problem is that there is not enough quiet zone on either side. The spec, IIRC, requires 9 modules on left and right, and this has about 2.

The detector is fairly lenient but not quite that much, to avoid false positives. Normally the area outside the image is treated like a big plane of white (and indeed, these scan just fine, on a white background like this page) so it would scan. For this format I see a note in the code that this is specifically disabled to avoid false positives.

You could try disabling this or generating a wider code to test that. If you find a change that doesn't increase false positives in the test set but makes this pass, that's probably worth committing.

Comment: Can you reproduce my problem?  How would one modify the code to accomplish what you suggest?  I cannot find anything in the class documentation.  Thanks!

Comment: It's not documented, it's hacking. Look in EAN13Reader for example. I think the much better solution is to generate a code with enough quiet zone. If you're not experienced in modifying code don't worry about trying to modify it.